# Nhibernate mapping two ternary associations (I think)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have ran into quite an interesting mapping scenario. I have two entities (`Task` and `ProjectEmployeeFile`) that has two identical foreign keys (`ProjectId` and `EmployeeId`).

I am trying to find an elegant way to map a `Tasks` property to the `ProjectEmployeeFile` entity.

I think that the solution for one foreign key relationship would be by using a ternary association but I have no idea how to project this into multiple foreign keys.

I am using fluent nhibernate but if solving this issue with classic hbm files is the way to go I have no problem with mapping those classes manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have drawn a basic diagram to try to illustrate the scenario:

[image: A basic diagram to try to illustrate my scenario]

I have mixed property names with database column names freely here but I think the general idea is clear.

**update**

In order to clarify the domain model, here is the current entities and mappings, stripped to the minimum:

```
    public class Task
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectEmployeeFile
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }


public class TaskMap : ClassMap<Task>
{
    public TaskMap()
    {
        Table("Tasks");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Project).Column("ProjectId");
        References(x => x.Employee).Column("EmployeeId");
    }
}

public class ProjectEmployeeFileMap : ClassMap<ProjectEmployeeFile>
{
    public ProjectEmployeeFileMap()
    {
        Table("ProjectEmployeeFiles");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Project).Column("ProjectId");
        References(x => x.Employee).Column("EmployeeId");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mixing relational and oop concepts really complicates the matter. I can help you with the mapping, but please create a real domain model first.

Comment: @Diego : I have updated the question with more detail baout the entities and their current mapping. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the ProjectEmployeeFile. It has the same properties as Task. What does it represent?

Comment: @Diego : I have omitted all the irrelevant properties. An Employee can have many tasks in a project. A ProjectEmployeeFile exists once for any relevant Employee-Project pair. It holds data about the inclusion of the Employee in the project, the documents he signed, his salary for the project, his availability, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mapping *might* work (I haven't tested it):

```
<class name="ProjectEmployeeFile">
  ...
  <bag name="Tasks" inverse="true">
    <key column="ProjectId" property-ref="Project"/>
    <key column="EmployeeId" property-ref="Employee"/>
    <one-to-many class="Task"/>
  </bag>
</class>
```

I don't know if it's possible to do it with fluent, but you can mix them anyway.

Comment: Didn't get to try it eventualy and found another solution. anyway, now it works and is also supported in FNH: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/commit/58be48f2f536b16d31db9f6ee522d6ccd2acc4a8

Answer (score 0):

1. Ternary association should be done at DB level
2. In code, just add Tasks collection property to ProjectEmployeeFile
   Why is that not enough?

Comment: The big question is how should I map this 'Tasks' property?